# UINavigationControllerDelegate doesn't work when back twice

Tags: ios, swift

I use coordinator pattern with child coordinators. I have a problem with removing child coordinator of my child coordinator.

This is a sequence of my coordinators:

1. HomeCoordinator -> RoutineCoordinator (child of HomeCoordinator) -> ExerciseCoordinator (child of RoutineCordinator) -> CustomExerciseCoordinator (child of ExerciseCoordinator)

To get know when user pops view controllers I use method didShow from navigation controller delegate.

When I push view controllers, everything is ok, but I when I move back, method didShow is called only once. When I use back button twice, the second time didShow is not called.

Example:
**I move back from CustomExerciseCoordinator to ExerciseCoordinator and didShow works properly. Then I immediately move back to previous coordinator (RoutineCoordinator) and didShow is not called.**

I am not sure if it is needed to show all coordinators, because the code for each coordinator looks similar, but below it is shown.

```
  class HomeCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator {
        
        var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
        var navigationController: UINavigationController
        
        init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
            self.navigationController = navigationController
            
            navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
            super.init()
            navigationController.delegate = self
        }
    
        func start() {
            let vc = HomeFactory.makeHomeScene(delegate: self)
            navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
        }
    }
    
    extension HomeCoordinator: HomeCoordinatorDelegate {
    
        func goToWorkoutCreating() {
            let child = NewRoutineCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController, removeCoordinatorWith: removeChild)
            child.passWorkoutToHomeDelegate = self
            addChild(child: child)
            child.start()
        }

    class NewRoutineCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator {
    
        var exerciseNumber: Int?
        var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
        var navigationController: UINavigationController
        private var removeCoordinatorWhenViewDismissed: ((Coordinator) -> ())
    
        weak var passWorkoutToHomeDelegate: PassWorkoutToHome?
    
        init(navigationController: UINavigationController, removeCoordinatorWith removeCoordinatorWhenViewDismissed: @escaping ((Coordinator) -> ())) {
            self.navigationController = navigationController
            self.removeCoordinatorWhenViewDismissed = removeCoordinatorWhenViewDismissed
        }
  
        func start() {
            navigationController.delegate = self
            let vc = NewRoutineFactory.makeNewRoutineScene(delegate: self)
            navigationController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
            navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
        
    }

extension NewRoutineCoordinator: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

        guard let fromViewController = navigationController.transitionCoordinator?.viewController(forKey: .from) else {
            return
        }

        if navigationController.viewControllers.contains(fromViewController) {
            return
        }
        if let vc = fromViewController as? NewRoutineViewController {
            removeCoordinatorWhenViewDismissed(self)
        }
    }
}

        class ExerciseCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator {
                
            var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
            var navigationController: UINavigationController
            
            private var removeCoordinatorWhenViewDismissed: ((Coordinator) -> ())
            
            init(navigationController: UINavigationController, removeCoordinatorWith removeCoordinatorWhenViewDismissed: @escaping ((Coordinator) -> ())) {
                
                self.navigationController = navigationController
                self.removeCoordinatorWhenViewDismissed = removeCoordinatorWhenViewDismissed
            }
        
            func start() {
                navigationController.delegate = self
                let vc = NewExerciseFactory.newExerciseScene(delegate: self)
                navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
    
    extension ExerciseCoordinator: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    
            guard let fromViewController = navigationController.transitionCoordinator?.viewController(forKey: .from) else {
                return
            }
    
            if navigationController.viewControllers.contains(fromViewController) {
                return
            }
    
            if let vc = fromViewController as? NewExerciseViewController {
                removeCoordinatorWhenViewDismissed(self)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something is nil the second time you navigate back. This often happens to me when I instantiate a view controller inside a function which it gets de-initialized so my delegation doesn't work anymore. What I usually do is declare a variable outside the function and assign the instantiated view controller to it.

For Instance try:

```
var newRoutineCoordinator: NewRoutineCoordinator?


func goToWorkoutCreating() {
     let child = NewRoutineCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController, removeCoordinatorWith: removeChild)
      newRoutineCoordinator = child
      child.passWorkoutToHomeDelegate = self
      addChild(child: child)
      child.start()
}
```

Not sure the problem is there but this is just to give you an example.

You have `UINavigationControllerDelegate` inside an extension of NewRoutineCoordinator but It may be already nil by the time you navigate back.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It's really weird, because the problem appears when only when I set delegate for more than 1 child. With one child it works, but when the child has own child it doesn't.